# Group of polynomial $x^4+2$ in $\mathbb Q[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Describe the Galois group of the polynomial $x^4+2 \in \mathbb Q[x]$.

I've been able to see how to do this for $x^4-2$ and $x^4+1$ but am unsure how to do this for the polynomial above.

Based on the roots of $x^4+1$, $\{\sqrt[4]{-1},\zeta_4\sqrt[4]{-1},\zeta_4^2\sqrt[4]{-1},\zeta_4^3\sqrt[4]{-1}\}$, where $\zeta_4$ is a fourth root of unity, I think the roots of $x^4+2$ should be$$\{\sqrt[4]{-2},\zeta_4\sqrt[4]{-2},\zeta_4^2\sqrt[4]{-2},\zeta_4^3\sqrt[4]{-2}\}$$but am unsure.

I would then need to something similar to:$$\sqrt[4]{-1}=i^{1/2}=e^{{\pi i}/4}= \frac{\sqrt2+i\sqrt2}{2}=\frac{(1+i)\sqrt2}{2}$$but for $\sqrt[4]{-2}$.

Comment: Perfectly correct. Most people will write just $i$ for $\zeta_4$. You still need to decide the Galois group…

Comment: The galois group is $D_4$.

Comment: Do you need to determine the Galois group itself, or just its isomorphism type? It's easy to compute the degrees in the second expression in $[\Bbb Q(i, \sqrt[4]{2}) : \Bbb Q] = [\Bbb Q(i, \sqrt[4]{2}) : \Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2})] [\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2}) : \Bbb Q] = (2)(4) = 8$, but (up to isomorphism) the only subgroup of $S_4$ of order $8$ is $D_8$ (NB my convention for the labeling of the dihedral group differs from Peter's, so our answers agree).

Comment: I don't know. The problem just says to describe the group of the polynomial.

Comment: In that case, you probably need to describe all of the automorphisms of the field extension explicitly.